# AngularJS animation won't stop immediately when ng-show is false

Tags: angularjs, animation

this is my login form:

```
<div class="container login">
    <h2 class="header">Login</h2>
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="loginForm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputUsername" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUsername" placeholder="Username" ng-model="data.userName" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" ng-model="data.password" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="data.rememberMe"> Remember me
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <a ui-sref="forgotPassword">Forgot your password?</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="login(loginForm)" ng-disabled="loading">Sign in</button>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh glyphicon-refresh-animate login-refresh" ng-show="loading"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

as you can see the last span has an animation that will be triggered when the form is being sent

this is the css:

```
.glyphicon-refresh-animate {
    -animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation: spin2 1.5s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin2 {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when i set the $scope.loading back to false it will only hide the loading span after it finishes its animation round.

so lets say i change the animation time to 20 seconds, it will only hide the loading after something between 0-20 seconds (depending on the last run).

why is this happening?

Comment: I think that's part of the animation. You hide it but the way it hides when you have animation is that it "animates away". What happens if you change ng-show to ng-if ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps using ng-if instead of ng-show would fix this. ng-show merely shows and hides a DOM element, essentially toggling the "display" CSS attribute. Maybe this isn't enough to stop your animation. ng-if on the other hand doesn't even read the DOM element. It works as if the element doesn't exist in the HTML.

Comment: `ng-if` will also wait for animations to finish before deleting the element.

Comment: I see. I wasn't sure of it. Thought it would be worth a try, but I didn't have any way to test it myself.

Answer (score 1):

ngAnimate will wait until the animation has completed before hiding it.

You can prevent this by explicitly setting the animation to none:

```
.glyphicon-refresh-animate.ng-animate {
    -webkit-animation: none 0s;
    animation: none 0s;
}
```